# Bottom wall getting dirty

Tags: concrete, walls, concrete-block, gardening

I have an 8 foot retaining concrete wall. I painted it a few months ago, but it seems that when the water hits the soil it jumps back up and hits the bottom wall covering it in dirt.
I was wondering what I can do to prevent the wall getting dirty with soil.

[image]

[Bottom Wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX7qA.jpg)

I was thinking maybe digging a trench and pouring rocks. Not sure if that will work.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: That looks more like water marks from standing water or dirty water actually being wicked up the wall than splash marks. Are you sure that water doesn't pool here when it rains?

Comment: There might be some standing water, but it is along the 75 foot length of the wall and there is a slight incline.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is caused by soil splashing, you have to have the water hit something other than soil.

Your rocks might work (if they don't fill up with soil.) Plants might work, though it looks a bit like the plants you have are struggling there. Artificial turf would work without the issue of trying to keep real plants alive in a harsh place.

Answer (score 1):

I would place pavers around the perimeter to prevent water hitting the soil and splashing dirt onto the wall.
If you slope the pavers away from the wall the water can run off.

Comment: Pawers = paving slabs?

Comment: I tried putting some patio pavers once and had a real hard time getting them leveled and looking nice. Didn't last long...

Comment: @Rick I assume you used pavers sand underneath for leveling